# ListView in Listview - SelectedIndex of parent not set when selecting child

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I have a UI which displays a ListView in a ListView:

```
<ListView
    SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ParentViewModel.SelectedParentIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ParentViewModel.ParentViewModels, Mode=OneWay}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:ParentViewModel">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentName}" />

                <ListView
                    SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedChildIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels, Mode=OneWay}">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:ChildViewModel">

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildName}" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I click on a parent element the SelectedParentIndex gets set and when I click on a child element the SelectedChildIndex gets set.

**My problem is** that when I click on a child element i don't know to wich parent element it belongs because the SelectedParentIndex is not set. How can I solve this?

And the flow how it should be:[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what your problem is?

Comment: I want get the SelectedParentIndex also updated when clicking on a child element which is currently not the case

Comment: Why would the parent index update if you were clicking on one if the parent's children? Can you please provide pictures or some more clarity on what you're trying to achieve. This is a really hard to understand question.

Comment: I have created a small drawing of the flow. From the UI I want to call a method where I have to provide the SelectedParent and SelectedChild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an event in. Here is a compiled working example.

```
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding ParentViewModels, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedParentIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParent,Mode=TwoWay}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentName}" />

                        <ListView                        
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels, Mode=OneWay}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedChildIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChild,Mode=TwoWay}">   

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildName}" />

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here are the cs files. Please pay close attention to the structure.

The `MasterViewModel` is your `DataContext` for your `View`. It handles the `SelectedParent`, the `SelectedParentIndex` and your parents collection.

```
      public class MasterViewModel : ViewModelBase
      {
        private ParentViewModel _SelectedParent;

        public ParentViewModel SelectedParent
        {
            get { return _SelectedParent; }
            set 
            { 
                _SelectedParent = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParent"); 
            }
        }

        private int _SelectedParentIndex;

        public int SelectedParentIndex
        {
            get { return _SelectedParentIndex; }
            set 
             { 
                 _SelectedParentIndex = value; 
                 OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParentIndex"); 
             }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ParentViewModel> ParentViewModels
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        public MasterViewModel()
        {
            ParentViewModels = new ObservableCollection<ParentViewModel>();
            LoadData();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                ParentViewModel parent = new ParentViewModel();
                parent.ChildChangedEvent += Parent_ChildChangedEvent;
                for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
                {
                    ChildViewModel child = new ChildViewModel() 
                                         { ChildName = "Child " + y };
                    parent.ChildViewModels.Add(child);
                }
                ParentViewModels.Add(parent);
            }
        }

        private void Parent_ChildChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedParent = (ParentViewModel)sender;
        }
    }
```

Your `ParentViewModel` contains your `SelectedChildIndex`, your `SelectedChild` and your `ChildViewModels` collection. It also has a name property

Notice that I added an `EventHandler` to your `ParentViewModel`. When the `SelectedChild` is updated, it fires the event off. Then, we handle this event in the `MasterViewModel` where we can force the `SelectedParent` to update.

```
    public class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public String ParentName { get; set; }

        private int _SelectedChildIndex;

        public int SelectedChildIndex
        {
            get { return _SelectedChildIndex; }
            set 
            { 
               _SelectedChildIndex = value; 
               OnPropertyChanged("SelectedChildIndex"); 
            }
        }

        private ChildViewModel _SelectedChild;

        public ChildViewModel SelectedChild
        {
            get { return _SelectedChild; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedChild = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedChild");
                if (ChildChangedEvent != null)
                {
                    ChildChangedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> ChildViewModels
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        public event EventHandler ChildChangedEvent;

        public ParentViewModel()
        {
            ChildViewModels = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Your `ChildViewModel` just has a name property.

```
    public class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _childName;

        public string ChildName
        {
            get { return _childName; }
            set 
            { 
              _childName = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged("ChildName"); 
            }
        }

    }
```

The ViewModelBase just updates the UI

```
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works as it should with the new eventhandler. Appreciate your time spent. Well done